# Can you paint parts of an image onto another image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image, texture-painting

Is there a way to paint parts of a source image onto a canvas image?

It's also important to use scale while painting.  For example, if the source image is a heart, can I paint it on the canvas image in different sizes?  How can I do this?

Comment: You cant really do that; you'll want use the texture painting tools instead.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms huh?

Comment: @gandalf3 Wait.... what canvas (I thought he meant dynamic paint)?

Comment: Hm.. Could be, but I didn't get that impression at first. I think the OP wants the texture painting tools (clone brush? Or maybe brush textures?).

Comment: I know it must be possible. I did it once by accident. possibly stencil option? I could paint in different sizes as I zoomed in or out. But it painted with opacity even with the brush power at 100%. Could be due to a mask. Not dynamic paint I'm looking for, think that is for animation(and way above my level).  To clarify my question: source image= what I want to paint. canvas image= where I paint on and what will be the image texture for an object (mesh).  Thx

Comment: @Toonpix updating answer... they've changed the options since I last used this tool

Comment: @GiantCowFilms that's what I need but am lost at step 8

Comment: @Toonpix do you wan't paint a pattern for hearts or one heart?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms  it works!   the hearts was an example to try and explain that  you cold use the same part of an image and paint it with different sizes. I tried with your answer and steps and then used 'stencil'. It goes exactly how I wanted after a month of trial and error. Glad I found this useful site. I can't thank you enough, have a great weekend and holidays.

Comment: @Toonpix could you mark it as accepted, it closes the question (its that check mark button on the upper right corner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You need to use the texture painting tools:**

1. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode
2. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything and then UV unwrap you object <kbd>U</kbd>*smart UV project*
3. Change your view to the UV image editor[image]
4. Open your image that you wan't to paint on (You can create a new blank one as well)[image]
5. Change your view back to 3D
6. Change into texture painting mode:
   [image]
7. In the slots tab, set the painting mode to image, and select your image from the drop down.
   [image]
8. Set up your brush[image]
9. **Configuration:**

   - Set the Texture to you're image:
     [image]
   - Set the brush mapping to tiled adjust the settings to make it look right.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the *Clone Brush* in *Texture Paint*.

[image]

This requires two UV mapped images with two different UV-maps

[image]

This is also useful to add dirt, rusty edges etc. to a texture.

Answer (score 1):

With the recent versions of blender, you also now have the option to use a brush texture as Stencil, and when setting the texture to use Stencil mapping in either Brush texture or Brush Mask texture, you get a floating drawing of the image in the 3d view from user perspective. You can rmb to move it, shift-rmb to scale it and ctrl-rmb to rotate it. With the use of a second image in the Brush Mask channel, you use alt-rmb ot move, shift-alt-rmb to scale and ctrl-alt-rmb to rotate that mask and can combine to create interesting effects.[image: image as stencil]