# Texture painting in Cycles

Tags: image, texture-painting

Is it possible to use an external image as a brush in Cycles texture painting?  When I hit the checkered box to browse to an external image, the only option I get is for a black blank texture.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/can-you-paint-parts-of-an-image-onto-another-image. When you get that "black blank image" you should navigate to Properties Editor > Textures tab and find this image in Brushes section, where you can assign any external image to "brush". This is explained in linked answer as well.