# How can I blend two textures together using a brush?

Tags: texturing

I have a game in unity, I made a scene with a terrain brush, in order to blend two textures together, but with blender I have difficulties in doing the same

Unity:
[image]

Blender:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/can-you-paint-parts-of-an-image-onto-another-image/21267#21267

Comment: It doesn't help me, but thx for the comment.