# I have a 3D .obj file and four texture files. I would like to edit the files using the UV mode of Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have an ,obj file generated in 3d Zephyr that has four color texture files .png.  I need to edit some colors on the bottom so I loaded the files into Blender and unwrapped it.

I can see the wrapping and added the first .png file.  When I try to add the next .png it replaces the first picture under the unwrap.  I want the second .png to sit to the right of the first .prn and not replace it.

I would appreciate any help.*

Joe Kosednar
See attached;
[image: Screen shot of shot of problem]

Comment: The quadratic area in the UV editor is 0-1 space used for mapping 3d model to 2d texture. Any image data can't exceed that 0-1 space so it can't appear where UV islands are placed on your screenshot to the right of white image. If any UV islands exceed the quadratic area, texture will be repeated on them as many times as they exceed the area. I'm not sure so far what are you trying to achieve but if you want to paint on the first image with some data from second image use Texture Paint mode and brush set to Stencil. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21122/1245

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  I want to save each texture file with the wrapping for that portion so I can edit the islands in Gimp.  What does 0-1 space mean?

Comment: 0-1 space or UV texture space is shown with rectangle in the center of UV editor. It is called sometimes as 0-1 space because each vertex of the mesh gets coordinates on the UV map within 0-1 range. All UV islands should be placed within that rectangle. To do that automatically select all in UV editor and press Ctrl+P (space usage depends on UV islands). If you want to edit texture externally you can export UV layout https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/extracting-a-uv-layout and import it into editor as additional layer